# Cortana "Ask me anything" box disabled in IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, botframework, cortana, cortana-skills-kit

I have added my sample Bot to cortana. its working good in andriod device , when i ask like "ask sample bot" it will get connected to my bot . like wise I have been running my cortana skill set in andriod device , but in IPad or Iphone cortana when i ask like that , it get connect to bot and immediately the bottom textbox will be disabled , the box is grayed out, and I can't type into it .

Is there any unique specification for IOS cortana for connecting skill set ??

please help out .!!

Comment: Are you using Node or .NET SDK for BotBuilder? Can you post a screenshot of the Cortana errors you are seeing?

Comment: i have done my coding with .NET SDK for BotBuilder. code wise not getting any error  the problem is that its not showing the box for entering any input after connected to the skill , i will  be getting the first result which i asked , after that nothing to do with the cortana bot.

Comment: can you post a screenshot?

Answer (score 2):

Cortana Skills currently do not accept text input and hence you may be seeing the box being grayed out. The UX elements are slightly different across Android and IoS. Ideally using text input in the Cortana Skill flow is not supported just yet. Hope this helps.

Comment: yes , But including the voice command icon also grayed out , and even its working well in andriod  devices .